# Content says derivative but I think it should be partial derivative

Tags: calculus, notation

This content is about finding approximate solution of ode using artificial neural networks.

This content is from paper 'Artificial Neural Network for Solving Ordinary and Partial Differential Equation' by Lagaris, Likas and Fotiadis.

Let us consider a first-order ODE as follows:

$y'(x)=f(x,y(x)), y(a)=A$, $x \in [a,b]$

In this case, the ANN trial solution is written as

$y_{t}(x)=A+(x-a)N(x,\overrightarrow{p})$ where $N(x, \overrightarrow{p})$ is the output of feed-forward network with one input unit for $x$ and weights $\overrightarrow{p}$. We can see that $y_{t}(x)$ satisfies initial condition by construction.

Our goal is to minimise this error function

$E[\overrightarrow{p}]=\sum_{i}\left\{ \frac{dy_{t}(x_{i})}{dx}-f(x_{i},y_{t}(x_{i}))\right\} ^{2}$

where $x_{i}$ are points in $[a,b]$ and $y_{t}$ denotes the trial solution. The derivative of $y_{t}$ can be written as:

$\frac{dy_{t}(x)}{dx}=N(x,\overrightarrow{p})+(x-a)\frac{dN(x,\overrightarrow{p})}{dx}$

My question is at the point where they say

$\frac{d(y_t)}{d(x)} = N(x,p) + (x-a)(\frac{dN(x,p)}{dx})$.

Here shouldn't we get

$\frac{\partial t}{\partial x} = N(x,p) + (x-a)\frac{\partial (N(x,p))}{\partial x}$?

Since both $y_t$ and $N(x,p)$ are functions of $x$ & $p$(weights)? I'm saying $y_t$ as a function of $x$ and $p$ since $y_t$ consists of $N(x,p)$ which is a function of $x$ and $p$. Please give your suggestions on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Actually, it's unreadable. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for that. I hope its readable now.

Comment: Yes, it is readable.

Comment: I think that you have missed out a crucial word in your rendering of the text: at one stage the $p$ are called "parameters". That seems to  mean that they are not being treated as "variables" and so the ordinary differentiation symbols are used. I think it's a matter of taste/convention, and personally I find it confusing - but there you are!

Comment: If they are treating p as parameter then they shouldn't have written N(x,p). As this suggests both x and p(vector) are variables.

Comment: Also during back propagation we have to find derivative of error function with respect to weights(p) so p can't be 'non-variable'.

Comment: @Tan I agree that this is confusing, but people do abuse notation every day of the week. "Parameter" is not well-defined, but it doesn't mean non-variable: more "fixed for the moment while I do this step".

Comment: "Parameter" is probably a term of art here for weight (as in the weights of an artificial neuron).